# Macro that pushes data from one Sheet to another based on dates

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new when it comes to building macros. And am not really familiar with how to build one.

But I'm trying to use the macro recorder to make one that will automatically copy data from one sheet labeled "Report Calculator" and push it to another sheet in the same workbook labeled by dates.

My sheets are labelled "1", "2","3" etc....Is it also possible to add a filter to the macro so that it will push the data to the worksheets based on dates? My apologies if what I'm asking is confusing.

This is the code I get when i use the recorder and I'm getting a debug error

```
Sub Report1()
'
' Report1 Macro
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-11, -7).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-16, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the text of the error you're getting.